# Is there a difference between self and Self in PHP?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I just noticed that when I write `self::` in Microsoft Visual Studio Code it becomes dark blue but when I type `Self::` it becomes seagreen. Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: It's very unusual to uppercase keywords so may editors don't even realise it's possible. I remember a major IDE where the static analysis engine could not even see classes if declared using `Class` instead of `class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functionally no, keywords are case-insensitive so `True`, `Array`, `FaLsE`, `clASS lol {...}` are all fine.

But Visual Studio is probably seeing `\b[A-Z_]\w+` as a class name, hence the different syntax highlighting.

Ideally, all keywords should be lowercase anyway, so stick with that if you can.